# MVC3 Action only accepting some of the parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

From the view I have:

```
$('#roles').button().click(function () {
    $.get('@Url.Action("load_manageRoles","Staff",new {muid = Model.UserID,Column = sort.Column,Direction = sort.Direction,page =(int?)ViewBag.page,upid=upid})',
        function (data) {
            $("#dialog-role-management").html("").html(data);
            $("#dialog-role-management").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 500,
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $("#dialog-role-management").html("");
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                }
            });
            $('#dialog-role-management').show();
        });

});
```

Using firebug I am seeing that all the parameters are being filled with valid values.

The action looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult load_manageRoles(Guid muid,GridSortOptions sort, int? page,String upid)
    {
        ....

        }
```

The odd thing that is happening is page and upid are not being populated and are null as a result even though it appears like I said earlier that from firebug correct values are being passed in. However, muid and sort are being passed correctly.

Very confused and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Chris

**UPDATE 1:**

Thank you for the response double checked that but it is correct. The details of the controller are irrelevant and I must not have made that clear initially.  The problem lies in the data being passed up to the server is not being parsed. Here are the parameters as captured by firebug to the server:

```
Column  UserName
```

Direction   Ascending

muid    f4ab6784-fbd3-4386-80d7-6b186eb04c52

page    1

upid    dc8f4336-0903-4875-848e-a1b30098a457

for the sake of testing if I flip flop the values for muid and upid the muid is still accepted and upid is still null. Also, if I change upid from string to guid it is still null.

**UPDATE 2**

I flipped the order of the parameters in jquery from muid=xx, upid=xx, etc...  to upid=xxx, muid=xxx, etc... and the results were muid is now null and upid has value. I also repeated the update 1 tests on the new order with the same results. It seems to only be accepting the first parameter for some reason.

**UPDATE 3**

Making progress it seems the action is only accepting the first parameter. I tested this by rotating all the parameters and combos.  Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Thanks for the responses!!

Comment: Those values are null because they have incorrect values which are parsed on server. Check the request from browser

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have subscribed to the `.click()` event of some button. If this is a submit button of a form or an anchor you need to cancel the default action by returning false from your click callback.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Capitalization poblem here:

```
(int?)ViewBag.page
```

should be:

```
(int?)ViewBag.Page ????
```

With out seeing the whole corresponding Controller Action its all guess work really.

Where is the 'upid' declared and assigned?

`upid=upid`

Comment: Thank you for the response double checked that but it is correct. The details of the controller are irrelevant and I must not have made that clear initially.  The problem lies in the data being passed up to the server is not being parsed. Here are the parameters as captured by firebug to the server:

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have to disagree with you saying the controller are irrelevant, if you haven't declared  (int?)ViewBag.page in the contoller then calling (int?)ViewBag.page in returned View will return null, resulting in what could be null values being passed to the contoller.

Comment: Oh I see what you were saying. I misunderstood I thought you were asking about the code inside the action which is irrelevant because the error is occuring before that section of code. As you can see from the update 1 the value being passed is 1. Each parameter has a value when being passed to the controller. I am in the process of removing parameters in a test to figure out which one is offending.